# Seperate and process odd named text files from an even named text files in Python

Tags: import, shutil

I am  new to programming & python and is trying to write a program to process astronomical data.I have a huge list of files naming like ww_12m_no0021.spc, ww_12m_no0022.spc and so on. I want to move all the odd numbered files and even numbered files in two seperate folders.

```
import shutil
import os


for file in os.listdir("/Users/asifrasha/Desktop/python_test/input"):
    if os.path.splitext(file) [1] == ".spc":
        print file
        shutil.copy(file, os.path.join("/Users/asifrasha/Desktop/python_test/output",file))
```

which is actually copying all the spc file to a different folder. I am struggling a bit on how I can only copy the odd number files (no0021, no0023…) to a seperate folder. Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import shutil

# Modify these to your need
odd_dir = "/Users/asifrasha/Desktop/python_test/output/odd"
even_dir = "/Users/asifrasha/Desktop/python_test/output/even"

for filename in os.listdir("/Users/asifrasha/Desktop/python_test/input"):
    basename, extenstion = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if extenstion == ".spc":
        num = basename[-4:]  # Get the numbers (i.e. the last 4 characters)
        num = int(num, 10)   # Convert to int (base 10)
        if num % 2:    # Odd
            dest_dir = odd_dir
        else:          # Even
            dest_dir = even_dir
        dest = os.path.join(dest_dir, filename)
        shutil.copy(filename, dest)
```

Obviously you can simplify it a bit; I'm just trying to be as clear as possible.

Comment: All correct, just change `basename.split("_")` since that would give you 'no00021' in one of his examples. ;)

Comment: Right, I'll change that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files are named `ww_12m_no` followed by the number:

```
if int(os.splitext(file)[0][9:])%2==1:
    #file is oddly numbered, go ahead and copy...
```

If the length of the first half of the name changes, I would use regex... I didn't test the code, but that's the gist of it. I'm not sure this question belongs here though...